# FilterBar How to get Controls?

Tags: sapui5

I have a filterbar (sap.ui.comp.filterbar.FilterBar) in a dialog, This dialog is opened some times and I want clear the filterbar before open it.

But if I use filter.getAllFilterItems() its return a list of FilterItems with aggregation "Controls" empty.

```
<fb:FilterBarclear="onClear" showClearOnFB="true" search="onSearch" advancedMode="true" filterBarExpanded="false">
    <fb:filterGroupItems>
        <fb:FilterGroupItem groupName="G1" name="BUKRS" label="{i18n>lblBukrs}">
           <fb:control>
               <Input type="Text" />
           </fb:control>
     </fb:FilterGroupItem>
</fb:FilterBarclear>
```

I found a internal method (_retrieveCurrentSelectionSet) that return all controls, but I looking for a better solution.

Comment: Have you tried the ClearVariantSelection method ?

Comment: Yah, don't work, I don't have variants on my FilterBar..

Comment: if you can grab the dialog instance, you should be able to use byId('Control_Id') on that dialog instance. It would mean you need to give controls Id's of course.

Answer (score 0):

From your controller you can instantiate the fragment like :

```
var fragment = sap.ui.xmlfragment("fragmentId", "path.to.fragment.xml", controllerInstance);
```

This will allow you to grab a specific Fragment control at anytime like below:

```
var fragmentControlInstance = sap.ui.core.Fragment.byId("fragmentId", "controlIdYouAreLookingFor");
```

Then should be able to do fragmentControlInstance.setValue("") or whatever you like to use to clear

The API docs should help you also.

Edit - Spelling

Edit 2 - Clarification

Also docs here should help : https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/8b325518a2ae48ee91eb2dacda1d1420.html

Comment: It's a way, but why get one-by-one if the componet has de array with controls, Why method getAllFilterItems return control's aggregation empty? is there an error in my xml? Or is it a component error/bug?

Comment: You said it yourself that you do not have any variants on your FilterBar and, from the api references, the GetAllFilterItems method "Retrieves filters belonging to the current variant". 
That might be why your control's aggregation comes up empty.

Comment: I set partOfCurrentVariant="true" for FilterGroupItems and still returning aggregation control empty

Comment: I am not sure why the control aggregration is failing to return but I also have not used filters in a dialog so I cannot comment why it is or what the correct way to achieve it is.